# How or when exactly does immutability help React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been looking into React.js. I was wondering if/when React.js relies on immutability for making decisions. I kinda get why it helps developers (elaboration in the context of React will be appreciated) but how does it help React itself?

How does it come into play for things like Virtual-DOM, shouldComponentUpdate, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, immutability is heavily used when I combine React with Redux. By using Redux, we create a data store which contained app state and will be **shared** across components. Redux encourage us to use pure function, which means there will be no mutation inside of it. For more explanation https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#what-are-the-benefits-of-immutability